# How to correctly install the latest Mono, Moonlight and Monodevelop instead of the version in Ubuntu repository?

Tags: mono

I would like to

- have the latest stable (2.8) Mono stack (Mono, Moonlight with Firefox plugin, Monodevelop, Monodoc, etc) on Ubuntu 10.10
- not have any remains of old Mono 2.6 which is available in Ubuntu repos,
- get all the mono-depending packages satisfied (I am afraid they will complain if I don't install Mono 2.6 from packages and install manually downloaded Mono 2.8 instead)

How do I acheive this?

Answer (score 2):

This is a somewhat vague answer, I know, but I hope it helps:

- Download the appropriate tarballs from http://ftp.novell.com/pub/mono/sources-stable/
- Follow the instructions for compiling at http://www.mono-project.com/Compiling_Mono_From_Tarball

The only dependencies listed on the latter page ARE NOT necessary for version 2.8, so you should (hopefully) have most everything you'll need already. But you're probably much more knowledgeable about this than I am, so hopefully the instructions there will give you all the info you need. Also, if you build from source, you shouldn't have any problems with the Ubuntu repo versions (unless you haven't completely uninstalled them already).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use http://www.badgerports.org. The badgerports provides updated Mono-related packages for Ubuntu.

Comment: that's for 10.04.

Comment: Seems that there is still no Mono 2.8 on badgerports :-(